# radio buttons in an imported module

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, module

I am creating a gui application in python 3.10 windows 11 and it has become quite large.

To simplify it I am trying to use and understand modules

I would like to import a module that asks the user to choose from a grid of radiobuttons containing thumbnails with the chosen value returned to the main program.  Simplifying as much as possible I have written two test programs, testmain.py and testmodule.py.

They don’t work and  I am beginning to think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of modules

Any pointers or help much appreciated
testmain is

```
from tkinter import *
import testmodule
testscreen=Toplevel(bg="green")
file_number=IntVar()
testmodule.buttons()
print(file_number.get())
testscreen.mainloop()
```

and testmodule is

```
from tkinter import *
def buttons():
    testscreen=Toplevel(bg="lightblue1")
    file_number=IntVar()
    button1 = Radiobutton(testscreen,text=1,variable=file_number,value=1)
    button1.pack
    button2 = Radiobutton(testscreen,text=2,variable=file_number,value=2)
    button2.pack
    testscreen.wait_variable(file_number)
    testscreen.destroy()
    return(file_number.get())\\\
```

Comment: _"They don’t work"_ - what does that mean? What do they do that is different from what you expect? Does the program crash? Are the radiobuttons invisible? Something else?

Comment: sorry that was unclear,  I expected to get a window showing two buttons on a light blue background generated by the module and waiting for one button to be clicked. Instead I get three empty windows, green, lightblue, and uncoloured default white and the program terminates without error.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to open a window, refer to the main form, **not** `Toplevel`. That is the way you used testmain.py

When you want to open another window, refer as `Toplevwel`. That is the way you used `testmodule.py`.

You cannot add background at the start of testmodule. You will get an error `TypeError: Tk.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bg'`

In `testmain`, you cannot use `file_number=IntVar()` and `print(file_number.get()`) to get data from another module. So comment out for both.

In `testmodule.py`, in line 11 add a print function. So you can see debug.

Btw, Don't used wildcard `from tkinter import *`

I modified in `testmodule`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import testmodule

 
testscreen = tk.Tk(bg='green')
testscreen.configure(bg='green')
 
testmodule.buttons()
 
testscreen.mainloop()
```

In `testmodule.py`, in line 11, just add print().

```
testscreen.wait_variable(file_number)
    print(file_number.get())

    testscreen.destroy()
    return(file_number.get())
```

Screenshot:

[image]